# "unsigned int" prints as a negative number?

Tags: objective-c

I am taking an integer, in this case 192, and left shifting it 24 spaces. The leading 1 is causing it to become negative, it seems.

```
unsigned int i = 192;
unsigned int newnumber = i << 24;
NSLog(@"newnumber is %d",newnumber);
```

I am expecting 3,221,225,472 but I get -1,073,741,824 (commas added for clarity)

An unsigned integer shouldn't be negative right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you *reinterpret* it in `NSLog` as a signed integer. You should use `%u` to see an unsigned value.

There is no way for a function with variable number of arguments to know with certainty the type of the value that you pass. That is why `NSLog` relies on the format string to learn how many parameters you passed, and what their types are. If you pass a type that does not match the corresponding format specifier, `NSLog` will trust the specifier and interpret your data according to it. Modern compilers may even warn you about it.

Comment: Aha. Makes perfect sense. I thought I was losing my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You wan to do `NSLog(@"newnumber is %u",newnumber);`

`%d` converts it back to a signed int.

Answer (score 7):

`%d` means "signed integer"; use `%u` for "unsigned integer".