# Why doesn't assigning a negative integer to an unsigned int cause an error?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int i;
    i = -12;
    printf("%d\n" , i);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I run the above code in Visual Studio 2012. Because I know `unsigned` refers to nonnegative numbers, I expected the program to report an error. Why does it still run smoothly and print the output?

Comment: This is undefined behavior FYI.

Comment: I thought *unsigned* overflow is well-defined?

Comment: Presumably Ed meant that it is UB to use `%d` with `printf`, but give an `unsigned int` as corresponding argument. (Which is true).  The argument has to be `int`, or a smaller type that promotes to `int` under the default argument promotions.

Comment: You were expecting consistency from C??

Answer (score 3):

As 200_success alluded to, there are two things going on here that are combining to produce the correct output, despite the obvious problems of mixing unsigned and signed integer values.

First, the line `i = -12` is implicitly converting the (signed) `int` literal value `-12` to an `unsigned int`. The bits being stored in memory don't change. It's still `0xfffffff4`, which is the twos-complement representation of `-12`. An `unsigned int`, however, ignores the sign bit (the uppermost bit) and instead treats it as part of the value, so as an `unsigned int`, this value (`0xfffffff4`) is interpreted as the number `4294967284`. The bottom line here is that C has very loose rules about implicit conversion between signed and unsigned values, especially between integers of the same size. You can verify this by doing:

```
printf("%u\n", i);
```

This will print `4294967284`.

The second thing that's going on here is that `printf` doesn't know anything about the arguments you've passed it other than what you *tell* it via the format string. This is essentially true for all functions in C that are defined with variable argument lists (e.g., `int printf(const char *fmt, ...);` ) This is because it is impossible for the compiler to know exactly what types of arguments might get passed into this function, so when the compiler generates the assembly code for *calling* such a function, it can't do type-checking. All it can do is determine the *size* of each argument, and push the appropriate number of bytes onto the stack. So when you do `printf("%d\n", i);`, the compiler is just pushing `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes onto the stack. It can't do type checking because the function prototype for `printf` doesn't have any information about the types of any of the arguments, except for the first argument (`fmt`), which it knows is a `const char *`. Any subsequent arguments are just copied as generic blobs of a certain number of bytes.

Then, when `printf` gets called, it just looks at the first `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes on the stack, and interprets them *how you told it to*. Namely, as a signed `int` value. And since the value stored in those bytes is still just `0xfffffff4`, it prints `-12`.

**Edit:** Note that by stating that the value in memory is `0xfffffff4`, I'm *assuming* that `sizeof(unsigned int)` on your machine is 4 bytes. It's possible that `unsigned int` is defined to be some other size on your machine. However, the same principles still apply, whether the value is `0xfff4` or `0xfffffffffffffff4`, or whatever it may be.

Comment: Implicitly *converting*, not implicitly casting. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for spotting that. I'll correct it.

Comment: "The bits being stored in memory don't change"  - if you're using 2's complement representation. It is possible for the system to use other representations, in which case this conversion would change the bits.

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's true. However, I have personally never worked on a machine that didn't use two's complement representation for signed integers. I'm not suggesting that because *I* haven't seen such a machine, that your point is irrelevant. It's a valid point. However, the OP did mention Visual Studio 2012, and I'm unaware of any target architectures supported by Visual Studio that don't use two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to this [Objective C question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10273047/1157100).  The short answer is, two wrongs make a right.

`i = -12` is wrong, in that you are trying to store a negative number in an `unsigned int`.

`printf("%d\n", i)` is wrong, in that you are asking `printf` to interpret an `unsigned int` as a signed `int`.

Both of those statements should have resulted in compiler warnings.  However, C will happily let you abuse the `unsigned int` as just a place to store some bits, which is what you've done.

Comment: There is no "right" here.  The behavior is undefined.

Comment: `i = -12` is right, and `printf("%d\n", i)` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`i = -12;` is well-defined. When you assign an out-of-range value to an `unsigned int`, the value is adjusted modulo `UINT_MAX + 1` until it comes within range of the `unsigned int`.

For example if `UINT_MAX` is `65535`, then `i = -12` results in `i` having the value of `65536 - 12` which is `65524`.

It is undefined behaviour to mismatch the argument types to `printf`. When you say `%d` you must supply an `int` (or a smaller type that promotes to int under the default argument promotions).

In practice what will *usually* happen is that the system interprets the bits used to represent the unsigned int as if they were bits used to represent a signed int; of course since it is UB this is not guaranteed to work or even be attempted.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed saving the -12 as an integer and telling printf (by using %d) that it is a normal int, so it interprets the contents of said variable as an int and prints a -12.

If you used %u in printf you would see what it is you're really storing when intepreting the contents as an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

printing may work (as explained by many above) but avoid using i in your code for further calculation. It will give not retain the sign.